# Get names and key names in array than output as list

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get key names and sub key names from a file so I can output the results as a list like below.

Tom was banned by UserWhoBanned because Reason For Ban

Bob was banned by UserWhoBanned because Reason For Ban

Mike was banned by UserWhoBanned because Reason For Ban

This is the list in the file.

```
{
    "Tom": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Bob": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Mike": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    }
}
```

This is my javascript code

```
fs = require('fs');
var file = "./files/banned.json";
fs.readFile(file, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        //console.log("Error reading file: " + (err.stack || err))
    } else {
        var data = JSON.parse(content);         

        // Convert JSON object to string
       var transformed_content = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);

    }   
});
```

If I add the lines below.

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
console.log("key = "+keys);
```

After the parse content it will list something like Tom,Bob,Mike all on the same line which is not what I want. No matter what I try they always seem to come up joined together on one line.

Comment: `Object.keys` returns an array, hence `console.log(keys.join('\n'));` would log the keys one per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `console.log()` is meant to log only a single string. So either do:

```
console.log("key = ");
console.log(keys);
```

The above will give all the keys, or you can do something like:

```
console.log("key = " + keys.join("\n"));
```

But the best way to do this is using `map()` function. Because you're transforming or mapping the data:

```js
var data = {
  "Tom": {
    "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
    "reason": "Reason For Ban"
  },
  "Bob": {
    "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
    "reason": "Reason For Ban"
  },
  "Mike": {
    "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
    "reason": "Reason For Ban"
  }
};
Object.keys(data).map(user => {
  const {bannedby, reason} = data[user];
  console.log(`The user ${user} was banned by ${bannedby}because of ${reason}.`);
});
```

The output for the above code you get is:

```
The user Tom was banned by UserWhoBanned because of Reason For Ban.
The user Bob was banned by UserWhoBanned because of Reason For Ban.
The user Mike was banned by UserWhoBanned because of Reason For Ban.
```

Comment: Both versions you offered worked super, I am not sure which is best but just happy to see the output doing what I needed. thanks again

Comment: @CharlyWilly You're welcome. You made my day. Also `.map()` will be the effective one compared to `for` loop in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` loop like this:

```js
for (const name in data) {
  const ban = data[name];
  console.log(`${name} was banned by ${ban.bannedby} because ${ban.reason}`);
}
```

BTW, I recommend you to use `const` instead of `var` in your code, if you don't want to change their value later in your code.

Comment: wow, I have been banging my head against a wall all night trying to work this out and you guys solve it within seconds. Makes me feel like I have so much to learn. thanks

Comment: no problem, don't hesitate if you have other questions! you can also mark the answer solved your problem with the Check icon :)

Comment: It is making me wait 7 minutes before I can mark it as solved, I will mark it as solved for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the desired list using `for in` loop:

```
input = {
    "Tom": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Bob": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Mike": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    }
};

const output = [];
for(var key in input) {
    output.push(
        key + " was banned by " + input[key].bannedby + " because " + input[key].reason
    );
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Object.entries`, you can get `[key, value]` pairs and using `Array.reduce`, can get the result.

```js
const input = {
    "Tom": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Bob": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Mike": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    }
};

const result = Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc.push(`${cur[0]} was banned by ${cur[1].bannedby} because ${cur[1].reason}`);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [object destruction](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-object-destructuring/):

```js
const obj = {
    "Tom": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Bob": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    },
    "Mike": {
        "bannedby": "UserWhoBanned ",
        "reason": "Reason For Ban"
    }
}

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([name,{bannedby, reason}]) => `${name} was banned by ${bannedby.trim()} because ${reason}`);

console.log(result);
```